Nexus 3 with multiple docker repos
I have a virtual machine, nexus3 in docker, and nginx setup on machine, so nginx is proxy server to nexus3. And now i want to install second hosted docker repository.
Nexus3 version - 3.62.0-01
Nexus3 docker run command:
 docker run -dit --restart=unless-stopped -p 8081-8082:8081-8082 --name nexus -v nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3

nginx conf file:
server {
    server_name *************;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/*************/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/*************/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
 location /v2 {
     proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
   }
   location /v1 {
     proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
  }
   # Regular Nexus requests
   location / {
     proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
   }
}
server {
    if ($host = *************) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name *************;
    server_name _;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}


I added new repository and add new port to nexus docker-container, it starts but when I try to do some docker loginor docker pull it gives me 502 error.
I want to make 2 different separate docker repos in nexus with 1 server name like this:
xxx.com/1-repo/
xxx.com/2-repo/
With different accesses. 1st for anonimous access, 2nd with basic authorization
